# Shared Hierarchy duplication and LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's assume that I can only do this in SQLite.

I have two Tables.

```
State {
  DistrictID: int
  SubdistrictID: int
  CityID: Int
  name: varchar(36)
}
```

Theres an obvious heirarchy in the State table. A State has a number of Districts, Each district has a number of Subdistricts, each Subdistrict has a number of Cities.

The other table is the number of Students in a City, where the Students.CityID = State.CityID

```
Students {
  CityID: int
  number: int
}
```

I want to know take out the number of Students existing in a District '221'.

**QUERY**: `SELECT sum(students.number) from State LEFT JOIN Students students ON State.CityID = students.CityID WHERE State.DistrictID = 221 GROUP BY State.DistrictID`

So far so good, this does work. I get the total number of students from across all the cities that are in District 221.

#### Heres the complication.

Some **Cities are SHARED between Subdistricts**. In this case, a District have One city thats shared across two Subdistricts. This is reflected within the State Table.

```
State Table
Row0: DistrictID: 221; SubDistrictID: 332; CityID: 554
Row1: DistrictID: 221; SubDistrictID: 332; CityID: 555
Row2: DistrictID: 221; SubDistrictID: 333; CityID: 554
Row3: DistrictID: 221; SubDistrictID: 333; CityID: 557
```

The Rows 0 and 2 have the same city (554) shared across two Subdistricts - 332 and 333.

In this case, the above sql query would double the SUM() value as the same city is counted TWICE.

How am I to solve this complex duplication that logically arose because of this technically faulty, but realistical problem, by not changing the schema of the table? I tried using `distinct`, but it doesn't fit this purpose, and as such, doesn't work.

Comment: You need to decide what you want to do.  That is the first step.  How is the value calculated for cities that are split?

Comment: Theres no calculation there. Basically, value is shared (Uniquely) across both Subdistricts. A City is not split. If I look at the Aggregates in Subdistrict: 332, it should get me the city 554 And 555 with the city attributes as a whole. At the subdistrict level, city is unique.

but at district level, where subdistricts share cities. Things are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select distinct` to get one reference to each city in the district, before doing the `join`:

```
select sum(s.number)
from (select distinct cityid
      from state
      where destrictid = 21
     ) c left join
     students s
     on s.cityid = c.cityid
```

Comment: I had other Tables `Left Join`ing into the states table. Is there a way to do create  a subquery elsewhere?

Comment: @jasonIM . . . It is only possible to answer the question that is asked.  If you have another question involving additional tables, I would advise you to ask *another* question.  Editing this question might invalidate answers, drawing downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

`Sum` would add all the `Student.Numbers`. If you want the number of students you should use `count`. To give you an idea, if there were 2 students in that district, one with `Student.number` 1 and the other with `Student.Number` 4, `sum` would return 5 and `count` would return 2:

```
select sum(S.number) 
from Students S inner join State St on S.CityId = St.CityId 
where St.DistrictID = 221
```

Since you're looking for a single `DistrictId`, you don't need a `group by districtId`. Also, I'm using an `inner join` since you just want those students with a `CityId` in the `State` table.

EDIT:

You can join other tables as follows:

```
select D.DistrictName, sum(S.number) 
from Students S inner join State St on S.CityId = St.CityId 
inner join City C on St.CityId = C.Id
inner join District D on St.DistrictId = D.DistrictId
where St.DistrictID = 221 
group by D.DistrictName
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the wording wasn't right. Student.number is "Number of Students". I want to add the number of students of each cities. So sum() is apt here. I don't want the number of rows.

Comment: Okay @jasonIM, in that case, use `sum` in the query above.

Comment: I had other Tables Left Joining into the states table. Is there a way to do create a subquery elsewhere?